Horror movie where a woman is chased in the forest. Features a parrot
I'm struggling to remember the title of this horror movie. 
Key plot points

A woman gets in a car wreck because she's drunk.
Her best friend dies in the crash and she (the driver) goes to some place in the forest.
She realizes there's a creature lurking in the forest and puts cans on a string so when the creature comes close she'll know about it.
She gets a parrot to keep her company


Welcome to M&TV! Pretty sure I know what you're after, but please add as many basic details as you can remember: Year, Country\language, where you saw it etc. which would get your question more positive recognition.
